# AJAX rails check box using javascript .submit()

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, checkbox

I'm using Rails 3.1 and I need a checkbox to toggle and save to the database without the page refreshing or redirecting.

Let me preface by saying i'm fairly novice, if i'm coming at this problem from the wrong angle please let me know.

Here is my form:

```
<% form_for book, :remote => true do |f| %>
   <%= f.check_box :finished %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my jQuery javascript:

```
$('input#book_finished').live("click", function() {
    $(this).parent('form').submit();
});
```

The :remote = > true doesn't work when I submit via jQuery, but does if I throw in a submit button (which I can't have).  How can I submit on clicking the checkbox though JS?

Comment: Your JS should submit the form just fine. Of course in this case you'd have to handle the response as well yourself. What exactly happens?

Comment: It submits, then redirects to the show page ( I'm using a standard restful scaffold).  I tried changing the controller so there is no redirect and I get a missing template error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code so far only handles the submitting via a click on the checkbox. In order to submit the form via AJAX, you'll still have to catch the submit event, prevent the default behavior and send the form data:

```
$('#form-id').submit(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: this.method,
    url: this.action,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(){
      ... // do something in case everything went find
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```