# submit form in Rails without page reload

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, page-refresh, preventdefault

I have a problem with preventing a pagereload on submitting a form.

My HTML:

```
<%= form_for @foo, html: {multipart: true}, remote: true do |f| %>
   <%= f.check_box :bar, :id => "bar_id", :onchange => "submit_function(this.form)" %>
<% end %>
```

My Javascript:

```
function submit_function(form){
    form.submit(function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

My Controller:

```
def update

   // awesome things for update

   respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to request.referrer }
     format.js {}
   end
end
```

When clicking the checkbox , the JavaScript is triggered . The " form.submit " sends the form to the controller , but in this case the entire page is reloaded . I would like to prevent this reload.

I've also tried this, however, the page is also reloaded.

```
function submit_function(form){
  form.submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: this.method,
        url: this.action,
        data: $(this).serialize()
    });
    return false;
  });
}
```

Is it necessary the " submit - function" to change before or is it them by pressing the checkbox to change ?

I have now tried something. Invites now the page no longer new, but the model is updated.

```
function submit_function(form) {

  $.ajax({
    type: form.method,
    url: form.action,
    data: $(form).serialize()
  });

  return false;
}
```

Now i have the problem with updating the partial which is changed. How can I do this with js?

OK, I get it. The request will be sent in js and no longer triggers the page reload. Using javascript I have edited the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be very similar to this situation: [AJAX rails check box using javascript .submit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467518/ajax-rails-check-box-using-javascript-submit)

What they do there is redefining the form submission, changing the behavior.

And as a basic recommendation: use rather unobtrusive JS instead of inlined onchange events

Comment: If i try this:         ->    function submit_function(form){

    form.submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: this.method,
            url: this.action,
            data: $(this).serialize()
        });
        return false;
    });

} ... in the javascript, it's also reloading

Comment: What does development.log say? Like "Processing MyController#update as HTML"? or "as JS"?

Comment: If I take the checkbox it sends as 'HTML'. Thus it triggers the "redirect_to request.referrer" in the controller. How can I do that to a 'js'?

Comment: According to this: http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms-data-type-with-jquery/, if you move format.js before format.html, the controller must respond in js. Or you must set dataType in the request explicitly. Not sure about that, haven't tried, but it may be worth trying at your side :)

Comment: Removing format.html will cause ActionController::UnknownFormat ... but i tried another thing .. see above

Comment: Ah, you are right. I just overlooked that in your JS part, concentrating on the controller code...